# Confusion on creating custom extender controls

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-ajax, toolbar, extender

I got 2 questions which are tightly coupled here.

When you look into the documentation on msdn about creating extender controls they preach that the new control must inherit from `ExtenderControl` which is part of the `Asp.net Ajax Library` reference:[read more about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386403.aspx#Y1026) but on reading more about extender controls i also found [this](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Walkthrough/ExtenderClasses.aspx) which states that control must inherit from `ExtenderControlBase` which is part of `AjaxControlToolkit`. Which on thinking doesn't make sense, Toolkit is already extender control collection and

1. why should my new control inherit from another base which actually inherits from `Microsoft Ajax Library` this also makes client who use my control to also include Toolkit dll whether they like it or not.
2. Also the manner properties set in both the reference i gave above is contrasting. Msdn does it with `get/set` methods but Toolkit docs prefer `GetValue, SetValue`. Which am to follow now.

3.This is not really a question though, but How do you maintain class library of controls mine is setup right now with no arrangement at all. Do you arrange them based on folders? Do you put them based on their function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) `ExtenderControl` is part of the .NET framework and is a *abstract* class to extend from to create your own extender controls using your own implementation.

`ExtenderControlBase` is from the external `AjaxControlToolkit` library which extends `ExtenderControl` to provide a more complete implementation that is further used within the library, and that can be used by others. It saves effort in building your own from scratch as you can leverage the implementation already in place.

2) Use whichever `get/set` syntax matches the reference you decide to use.

3) The convention is usually to use a folder structure that matches namespaces, grouped in a logical manner. Based on function sounds like a sensible way.

Comment: thanks for the answers but from clients point of view doesn't it make him feel "Why should i download/depend on something else" leave the client "I myself" am feeling the same

Comment: It shouldn't AjaxControlToolkit is developed by Microsoft as an extension of the framework. It's common practice to incorporate other libraries into a solution. There's no licensing restrictions on it, and the client will get a more robust, more thoroughly tested solution and can leverage further updates from future updates for free. There's no point reinventing the wheel if it rolls.

Comment: Yeah i think you are right, i should discuss this with my superiors then.Thanks